# how to add the Phonon::SeekSlider to horizontalSlider in qt

Tags: qt

I have added an horizontal slider on UI and i need to use this as slider in phonon audio player
i used an onClick function in an button and added an

```
Phonon::SeekSlider *slider = new Phonon::SeekSlider; 
slider->setMediaObject(moo);
 slider->show();
```

if i used this the slider is opening as another window .how can i map the horizontal i use it in UI to this seek slider in qt

Answer (score 1):

You create the slider without a parent. As [the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/application-windows.html) states "Any QWidget that has no parent will become a window". So when you create the slider make sure you set its parent QWidget, which will be one of the widgets in your UI.

From your question I make up you're already using a slider in your UI? Then simply don't use that one, but use the SeekSlider instead.